# How to show Native ads?

Tags: android, admob, native, ads, appodeal

I have already implemented admob Reward ads and want to show native ads. Really didn't get any useful source and stuck in this problem for 3 days. Can any one help me to show native ads please its an emergency issue.

I have tried appodeal also but got so many errors nothing else.

Comment: https://developers.google.com/admob/android/rewarded-video

Comment: what you mean by native ads?

Comment: https://developers.google.com/admob/android/native

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your XML

```
<com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/adView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    ads:adSize="SMART_BANNER"
    ads:adUnitId="YOUR UNIT ID" />
```

And this is how you can request for Ads

```
private AdView mAdView;

MobileAds.initialize(this, "Ads Key This is Different from UNIT ID");

mAdView = findViewById(R.id.adView);

AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();

mAdView.loadAd(adRequest);

mAdView.setAdListener(new AdListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAdLoaded() {
            Log.e("Add Listener", "AdLoaded");
        }

        @Override
        public void onAdFailedToLoad(int errorCode) {
            Log.e("Add Listener", "onAdFailedToLoad" + " - " + errorCode);
        }

        @Override
        public void onAdOpened() {
            Log.e("Add Listener", "AdOpened");
        }

        @Override
        public void onAdLeftApplication() {
            Log.e("Add Listener", "AdLeft");
        }

        @Override
        public void onAdClosed() {
            Log.e("Add Listener", "AdClosed");
        }
    });
```

Comment: I asked for Native ads not banner.

Comment: https://developers.google.com/admob/android/native follow this, if you need let me know will create a sample for you. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

what i have done for my app was implementing an imageview on top of all layouts as a framelayout. the idea was using [glide](https://github.com/bumptech/glide) and a link that goes into the app.
so what you need is two things

## 1) a redirect link that goes to a php file on your server and update the destination link (this way you can count clicks on the add)

## 2) an imageview in your app that loads the image from your server and has in contains that redirect link in it's onclick method.